# Windows takes up >40GB of disk space

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

I have a serious problem with disk space on my laptop (a Medion Erazer), since the size of the Windows folder just keeps growing for no apparent reason.

Currently, it is at 41.9GB, which is three times as large as the Windows Folder on my desktop PC (I use Windows 10 pro on both). Is there a reason for this? And is there anything I can do about it?

I have identified the main space sinks as being the folders System32/DriverStore (17,8 GB), Software Distribution (6,8 GB), and WinSxS (4,4 GB), and of these only the WinSxS folder is anywhere near as big on my desktop PC.

I have already tried uninstalling old drivers from the driver store, which reduced the size of the DriverStore folder by  3GB, but it's still bigger than my entire Windows folder on my desktop PC.

What is causing this extreme bloat? And is there anything I can do about it?

Comment: After performing disk cleanup as answered by @harrymc (which should et Windows to <<20 GB , you'll need to *continually* use *cleanmgr.exe* to keep it from getting overweight again... particularly after a Windows Update, After Update, cleaning may remove 4 GB or more of old files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Software Distribution folder**

The Software Distribution folder is used by Windows Update for downloading updates
before they are installed. From its size, it seems to contain an entire Windows
version.

I suggest to check in *Settings > Update & Security > Windows Update* if you see
"You're up to date". Even so, click on "Check for updates" to verify that nothing
is pending.

If no updates are pending, you may clear it up, this way:

Start an elevated Command Prompt (cmd) and enter the commands:

```
    net stop wuauserv
    net stop bits
    rename C:\windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.bak
    net start wuauserv
    net start bits
```

Reboot Windows and wait a day or two. If no harmful effects arrive,
you may delete the backup folder
`SoftwareDistribution.bak`.

**DriverStore folder**

This folder contains device driver packages that are ready to be installed.
It also contains old versions of drivers that might be used to roll-back
updated drivers.

It is best to let Windows manage this folder. But if it becomes too large,
it can be cleaned up.

- Create a restore point first before starting
- Run the Disk Cleanup Wizard by pressing the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
  and entering the command `cleanmgr.exe`
- In the Disk Cleanup for (C:) window, click the *Cleanup System Files* button
- Select the *Device driver packages* option
- Click OK.

The above method will likely be insufficient to remove most of this folder.
Removing more data will need to be done one driver after another with extreme
caution.

You need first to make a list of all drivers using `pnputil.exe /e > c:\drivers.txt`.
To delete all unnecessary drivers use the command `pnputil.exe /d oemNN.inf`,
where `oemNN.inf` is found in the list.

Be very cautious when doing that, and boot for Windows to restore drivers
wrongly deleted. Roll back to the saved System Restore point in case of an
unrecoverable error.

Comment: What you said about the Software Distribution folder was really helpful. I found out that there was apparently one or more windows updates still pending, that did not get installed because I had too little space left, and just kept piling up on one another. I ended up fixing this by uninstalling some other programs (which I would have liked to keep, but oh well...), after which Windows was able to install the updates (which took several hours). After that, I was able to do a system cleanup and free up around 20GB. Now both folders are down to a much more regular size (and Windows 17,6GB total)